# MacBook Pro 2021 14" WiFi with lower RSSI than MacBook Pro 2020 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, battery, hardware

I don't know if anyone here has noticed this, but in my MacBook Pro the received signal strength (RSSI) on the new 2021 Mac is lower than on my 2020 M1 MacBook Pro. The test was performed with both computers at the exact same spot on my desk, not with the 2 computers side-by-side.

At that specific spot, my work MBP 2020 13" has these values:

```
RSSI: -24 dBm
Noise: -90 dBm
Tx Rate: 1200Mbps
MCS Index: 11
```

The new MBP 2021 14" (M1 Max) has these values:

```
RSSI: -49 dBm
Noise: -83 dBm
Tx Rate: 583-780Mbps
MCS Index: 5-8
```

Both the MCS Index and the Tx Rate vary wildly on my 2021 MBP. It makes sense that it affects the Tx Rate since the MCS Index changes the modulation, but I don't understand why it changes in the first place, given that the signal values remain the same.

Has anyone ever noticed any changes to your WiFi signals? Has Apple screwed this hardware generation or is this all due to battery savings?

I am not a telecommunications expert so I don't know if, for instance, a **receiver** antenna could have its signal strength "boosted" by a power amplification. I know the transmitter antenna for sure depends on its power amplification. But what about the receiver? Could this be a software controlling the power on the WiFi antenna?

My laptops are at different macOS versions because the IT department hasn't approved an update on my work computer yet. So:

MBP 2020 13" M1: macOS 11.6.1
MBP 2021 14" M1 Max: macOS 12.0.1

More info:
Both laptops connected to the same WiFi network at 5Ghz 802.11ax (WiFi 6).
However, after a period of inactivity with the lid shut (such as overnight), the Monterey 2021 MBP will not reconnect as WiFi 6 automatically. I need to click on the WiFi logo and turn it off/on to reconnect as WiFi 6.

I appreciate any insights you might have. Thank you.

Comment: Very interesting data. As an experiment, would you mind re-running this a few more times with the 2021 machine rotated through 90 degrees on each of its axes (one axis at a time)? I'm curious to see if there's any correlation to antenna polarization.

Comment: Great idea! I will test as soon as I can.

Comment: Same problem here. MBP 13 2015 vs MBP 14 2021. Same spot, 5GHz wifi. RSSI significantly lower on 14", TX Rate around 49-20 on 14" while on 13" it is stable -176Mbps. Noise is the same. So yeah, the new MBP is having a problem with wifi.

Comment: It took me one year... but I've been running the tests over the course of this time. Absolutely no changes to values regarding MBP rotation. However, the overall WiFi speed has improved with the several macOS updates Apple released during this period, so I do think the software was throttling the speed when I originally posted this topic. Apple is crazy about battery duration and I believe they, sometimes, go way to far with it.